# Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ on a set $X$, can we find a non trivial measure on $(X, \mathcal A)$?

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose that $X$ is a non-empty set, and $\mathcal A$ is a non-trivial $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. I was wondering whether it is possible to find a non trivial measure $m : \mathcal A \to \Bbb R_{≥0} \cup \{+\infty\}.$

---

I know that this may be impossible if we require further conditions on the measure. For instance with invariance by translation and finiteness on compact sets and with $X=\Bbb R$, we can't have $\mathcal A = \cal P(\Bbb R)$ because of Vitali sets. But maybe we can find a non-trivial measure on $\cal P(\Bbb R)$.

My idea was the following. Consider the collection
$$\Bbb M = \left\{(\cal B, \mu) \mid
\cal B \subset \cal A \textrm{ $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ },
\mu : \cal B \to \Bbb R_{≥0} \cup \{+\infty\} \textrm{ non-trivial measure } \right\}$$
It is a non-empty collection because if $E \in \cal A$ is a non-empty set, then I can define $n(E) = 1 = n(X \setminus E), n(X)=2$, so that $(\{\varnothing, E,X\setminus E, X\} \,;\, n) \in \Bbb M$.

Moreover, $\Bbb M$ can be endowed with a partial order:
$$(\cal B, \mu) ≤ (\cal B', \mu') \iff \cal B \subseteq\cal B' \;,\; \mu'\big\vert_{\cal B} = \mu.$$
This turns $\Bbb M$ into an inductive set. By Zorn's lemma, pick a maximal element $(\mathcal E,m)$. If there was a set $F \in \cal A \setminus \cal E$, then I could extend $m$ by defining $m(F)=1$. Actually I'm not sure that this is sufficient to extend $m$ to $\sigma(\cal E \cup \{F\})$, in order to show that $\cal E \neq \cal A$ is impossible. Here I'm stuck...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would the delta measure at a point be considered non-trivial? ie. Fix $x_0 \in X$ and define $\mu(A) = 1$ if $x_0\in A$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: I didn't know this simple idea... This is a non-trivial measure for me.

Comment: Or generalize the counting measure, with $\tau(A) = |A|$ for finite $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\tau(A) = \infty$ for infinite set?

Comment: You need to specify not only that $E$ be non-empty, but also that $E$ be a proper subset of $X$. Otherwise, your putative measure $n$ is not well-defined, since $X\setminus E$ may be empty, in which case we would need $n(X\setminus E)=0\neq 1.$ In particular, if $X$ is a singleton, then your proof falls apart, and there are (arguably) *no* non-trivial measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Prahlad Vaidyanathan mentioned in the comments, consider the delta measure. Fix $x \in X$ and let 
\begin{align*}
m_x(A) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in A \\ 0 & x\not\in A \end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Then $m_x$ is a finite measure on $X$.
This can be generalized to $m = \sum_{x \in X} p_x \mu_x$ with $p_x \in [0, \infty]$.

Another possible measure would be to generalize the counting measure. On $\mathbb{N}$, the counting measure simply gives the cardinality of a set $N \subset \mathbb{N}$. So let 
\begin{align*}
m(A) = \begin{cases} |A | & A \text{ is finite} \\ \infty & \text{else}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
which again gives a measure on $X$.
Regarding invariance by translation, if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have
\begin{align}
m(A) =  m(\lambda+A)
\end{align}
for all $A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.