# Show that $1 \le f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k) \le 3$ for $V_k := q_k + V := \{q_k + v : v \in V\}$, $k \in \Bbb N.$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f : \mathscr P(\Bbb R) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a function with the following properties:
>
> $i) \ f(\emptyset) = 0,$
>
> $ii) \ f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)$ = $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(A_k)$ for disjoint sets $A_k$,
>
> $iii) \ f(A + c) = f(A)$ for every $A \subset \Bbb R$ and $c \in \Bbb R,$
>
> $iv)  \ f([0, 1]) = 1.$
>
> Furthermore, let $x \sim y$ iff $x - y \in \Bbb Q$ be an equivalence relation on $[0, 1]$. From every equivalence class, we choose exactly one representative, and $V \subset [0, 1]$ is the set of these representatives.
>
> Now, let $\{q_1, q_2, \ ... \}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[-1, 1]$. Define the disjoint sets $V_k := q_k + V := \{q_k + v : v \in V\}$, $k \in \Bbb N.$
>
> Show that
>
> $1 \le f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k) \le 3$.

I tried to wrap my head around this task for the last six hours, but I didn't come to a result yet.

What I know so far:

There are two types of equivalence classes here: one equivalence class that contains all rational numbers in $[0, 1]$ and
several (I guess infinitely many) equivalence classes that contain only irrational numbers. I realized that, given any
irrational number $i_k \in [0, 1]$, we obviously have $0 < i_k < 1$. When I choose $v = 0$ to be the representative of
the equivalence class of the rational numbers, I receive the interval $[-1, 2)$, while choosing $v = 1$ gives me 
the interval $(-1, 2]$. This just follows from summing up the rational numbers in $[-1, 1]$ and the different $v$ (which are 
bounded by $0$ and $1$) and then constructing the union of the $V_k$.

Now this is interesting because these intervals have "nearly" the length $3$, so I'd guess using the property $iv)$ here would
give me the inequality to the right somehow. For showing the inequality to the left, I tried to show that $[0, 1] \subset
\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k$. If I would be able to show this, the inequality to the left would even follow directly from $iv)$,
but I wasn't able to do it yet. Plus, I'm not quite sure whether $iv)$ is applicable exclusively for $[0, 1]$ or also for, let's say, intervals like $[2, 3]$.

So I would appreciate a **hint** for one of these two inequalities (or both, if it works similar in both cases). Please 
don't give a full solution. :-) Please note that this is a just a part of a bigger task, so it's possible that you
don't need all the premises I've written down before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

— Since $-1≤q_k≤1$, you easily get $$V_k = q_k + V \subset q_k+[0,1] \subset [-1,2]$$
Now you can compute $f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right)$, using the fact $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \subset [-1,2]$. You should get the right-hand side inequality.

— For the other inequality, try to show $[0,1] \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k$. If $x \in [0,1]$, then its class modulo $\sim$ is equal to $[x]_{\sim} = [v]_{\sim}$ for some $v \in V$. This means $x-v \in \Bbb Q$. Can you take it from here?

— We can prove the following useful lemma: if $A \subset B$ then $f(A) ≤ f(B)$.

— Notice that $V$ is usually called a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: Thanks! Seems like my thoughts went into the right direction, good. :-) Let's start with your hints on the right-hand side inequality: So I am right to assume that I can use $vi)$ in order to calculate $f([-1, 2])$?

Comment: @Julian  : iii) and iv) are useful for $f([-1,2])$.

Comment: Oops, switched the letters, of course I meant iv). :-) Okay then, I'll try it.

Comment: Maybe the only work would be to show that $f(\{a\})=0$ for any $a \in \Bbb R$. And for the LHS inequality, we have to show $A \subset B \implies f(A) ≤ f(B)$. This can be done by using (ii) and writing $B = A \sqcup (B \setminus A)$.

Comment: Now you're confusing me. What direction am I supposed to take? The one in your answer or the one in your comment?

Comment: The first sentence in my previous comment is about the RHS (more precisely, computing $f([-1,2])$). Then the comment is about the LHS.

Comment: For the RHS: Since we know the that $V_k$ is a subset of $[-1, 2]$, and since all the summands are non-negative by the definition of $f$, it follows that the sum of the $f(V_k)$ is less or equal the "sum" of $f([-1, 2])$. It's only left to show that this equals 3.

Comment: Now I don't know whether I can applicate iii) directly here or not.

Comment: Ahh, now I know what you mean with $f({a}) = 0$. If I'm able to show this, then I would be able to write $[-1, 2]$ as a union of three disjoint sets, and when I can exclude the single points that aren't in the interval, this means that all these disjoint sets possess the length $1$.

Comment: Could you give me another hint on the LHS? I don't see where $x - y \in \Bbb Q$ is taking me here.

Comment: $x-y=q_k$ for some $k$. Then $x=y+q_k$. The aim is to show that $x \in \bigcup_{k \geq 1} V_k$ ; you are very close to it :-)

Comment: Ah, that is obvious then. :-) First, I guess, we should note that we don't have just $x - y \in \Bbb Q$, but especially $x - y \in [-1, 1]$, the set of the  enumeration of the rational numbers that we defined in the beginning. Plus, we know that $y \in V$, therefore, $y + q_k \in V_k$, and thus, it is also part of the union.

Comment: As I wrote [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48560/discussion-between-julian-and-watson),  if you assume that $f(\{x\}) = a > 0$ for some positive real number $a$, then $f(\{1 ; 1/2 ; 1/3 ; 1/4 ; …\})$ is the sum of $f(\{1/n\})$ for $n \geq 1$ by (ii). But each $f(\{1/n\})$ equals $a$ by (iii). By the lemma I added to my answer, we would have $$f([0,1])=1 \geq f(\{1 ; 1/2 ; 1/3 ; 1/4 ; …\}) = \infty,$$ contradiction. Therefore $f(\{x\}) = 0$ for any $x \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks! That should also do the trick for the next task where I have to show that $f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty) \in \{0, \infty\}$. Of course it is possible that it equals $0$ because not only are all the $V_k$ disjoint, but we can also write them as a disjoint union of every element they contain. Applying $f(\{x\}) = 0$ and $ii)$ gives us $f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty)$  $= 0$ then. :) Just have to think about why it could also equal infinity.

Comment: @Julian : You can't have $f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right) = \infty$, since you've just proved an inequality involving $f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right)$… [By the way, I think that $f$ should allow taking the value $\infty$ in the definition in your yellow box.]

Comment: You're right, I corrected it. Yes, it's right that I can't have it equal $\infty$, but that would also be the answer to the next (and last) question, namely whether there can be such a function or not. I guess the answer is No then.

Comment: @Julian : your guess is the right one. Good job!

Comment: Or is there no need to show that it can possibly equal $\infty$? I mean, I also showed that is can possible equal $0$ which also contradicts the inequality from before.

Comment: Since $$X:=f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right) = \sum_{k \geq 1} f(V+q_k) = \sum_{k \geq 1} f(V) ≤ 3,$$ we have $f(V)=0$, but then  $X=\sum_{k \geq 1} 0 = 0$, contradicting $X \geq 1$. Therefore such a function $f$ (called "translation invariant measure on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$") can't exist.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867477) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition) for more details.

Comment: How did you conclude $f(V) = 0$? :-) And what is it about the question of $f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k) \in \{0, \infty\}$? Is it enough to show that it possibly equals $0$?

Comment: 1) You have an infinite sum of a constant number (namely $f(V)$). Since this infinite sum has a finite value (at most $3$), the constant number must be $0$. $\tag*{}$ 2) $f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right)$ is an infinite sum of a constant number. So it is either $0$ or $\infty$, depending on this constant number being $0$ or different from $0$.

Comment: In our case $f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right) ≤ 3$ so we get $f(V)=0$. Then $f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right)$ is a sum of zeroes, so it is $0$, whereas we proved $1 \leq f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right)$, whence the contradiction.

Comment: Man, I already lost it with measure theory, but by digging myself deep into this ask with the help of your tips, I think I actually fell in love with it. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: Damn, I don't see how to write $[-1, 2]$ as three disjoint sets. Is it something like $[-1, 0) \cup \{0\} \cup (0, 1) \cup \{1\} \cup (1, 2]$? Plus, I don't think I understood your proof for $f(\{x\}) = 0$. Why are you using $f$(\{$1 \over n$\}$)$? How is this connected to $a$?

Comment: @Julian : I think you should ask a new question. Just given the four axioms for $f$, we can deduce $f([-1,2])=3$.

Comment: That's what I thought too. There is really no need for the contradiction-proof above, right?

Comment: The fact $f([-1,2])=3$ has nothing to do with $V$. Only the (i)–(iv) suffice to prove it.

Comment: No, I meant the contradiction proof with $1 \over n$.

Comment: I don't know. I had this proof, but there may be an easier one. In any case, please ask a new question. This is far more suitable than comments.

Comment: Did it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015788/show-that-f-bigcup-k-1-infty-v-k-le-3-for-v-k-q-k-v-q-k-v