# Show that $f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k) \le 3$ for $V_k := q_k + V := \{q_k + v : v \in V\}$, $k \in \Bbb N.$

Tags: measure-theory

As wished in the old topic:

[Show that $1 \le f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k) \le 3$ for $V_k := q_k + V := \{q_k + v : v \in V\}$, $k \in \Bbb N.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015362/show-that-1-le-f-bigcup-k-1-infty-v-k-le-3-for-v-k-q-k-v-q-k/2015403?noredirect=1#comment4138169_2015403)

I open a new topic for the specific case

$f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k) \le 3$.

The premises are the same:

> Let $f : \mathscr P(\Bbb R) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a function with the following properties:
>
> $i) \ f(\emptyset) = 0,$
>
> $ii) \ f(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)$ = $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(A_k)$ for disjoint sets $A_k$,
>
> $iii) \ f(A + c) = f(A)$ for every $A \subset \Bbb R$ and $c \in \Bbb R,$
>
> $iv)  \ f([0, 1]) = 1.$
>
> Furthermore, let $x \sim y$ iff $x - y \in \Bbb Q$ be an equivalence relation on $[0, 1]$. From every equivalence class, we choose exactly one representative, and $V \subset [0, 1]$ is the set of these representatives.
>
> Now, let $\{q_1, q_2, \ ... \}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[-1, 1]$. Define the disjoint sets $V_k := q_k + V := \{q_k + v : v \in V\}$, $k \in \Bbb N.$

The suggestion was:

> — Since $-1≤q_k≤1$, you easily get $$V_k = q_k + V \subset q_k+[0,1] \subset [-1,2]$$
> Now you can compute $f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \right)$, using the fact $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k \subset [-1,2]$. You should get the right-hand side inequality.

I'd especially like to know how to write $[-1, 2]$ as an union of disjoint sets to calcuate that their sum is, in the end, equal to $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Prove that, for distinct $q,q' \in \mathbb Q$, $V+q$ and $V+q'$ are disjoint.
2. Prove that $\cup_{q\in [-1,1]}(V+q) \subset [-1,2]$
3. Prove that $f$ is increasing in the sense of $A\subset B \implies f(A)\leq f(B)$. (Hint: $B=A\cup (B\setminus A) \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset\ldots$)
4. Use 3. to derive $f(\cup_{q\in [-1,1]}(V+q))\leq f([-1,2])$.
5. Countable additivity of $f$ implies subadditivity of $f$ (you've probably already proved this for measures) ie $f(\cup_n A_n) \leq \sum_n f(A_n)$.

Property $(iii)$ and $5$ yield $f([-1,2]) = f([0,3]) = f([0,1] \cup [1,2] \cup [2,3])\leq f([0,1])+f([1,2])+f([2,3]) = 3\cdot f[0,1]=3$

Hence $f(\cup_{q\in [-1,1]}(V+q))\leq 3$

Comment: Thank you! :-) Note that 1. is already covered by the premises.